# Table row width is changing to do match an element which is not inside the table-row

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML structure for an input with an icon on its left side.

```
           <div class="fieldset">
                <p>Normal Input</p>
                <div>
                    <span><i class="icon-cart"></i></span>
                    <input name="">
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using `display:table` properties to style the structure to the desired layout demonstrated in the following image:

[image]

However, the icon (`<span>`) is stretching its width according to the title (`<p>`) above it just as the image below demonstrate:

[image]

Here is the current CSS used:

```
/*Fieldsets*/
.fieldset {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.fieldset:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

        /*Fieldsets > Labels*/
        .fieldset > p { 
            width: 1%;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }  

        /*Fieldsets > Input Container*/
        .fieldset > div {
            display: table-row;
            position: relative;
        }  

            .fieldset > div > * {
                display: table-cell;
              white-space: nowrap;
              vertical-align: middle;
                position: relative;
            }  

            /*Fieldsets > Input + Icon*/
            .fieldset > div > span {
                border: 1px solid #B0C2CE;
                padding: 5px 15px;
                font-weight: bold;
                width: 1%;
            }  

            /*Fieldsets > Input + Icon Senarios*/
            .fieldset > div > span:first-of-type {
                border-right: 0;
                border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
            } 

            .fieldset > div > span:not(:only-of-type) + input {
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            .fieldset > div > input + span {
                border-left: 0;
                border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
            }  

            .fieldset > div > span + input,
            .fieldset > div > span + textarea,
            .fieldset > div > span + select,
            .fieldset > div > span + .select-dropdown-single .select-dropdown-input,
            .fieldset > div > span + .select-dropdown-multi .select-input {
                border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
            }

            /*Fieldsets > Input + Help ToolTip Icon*/
            .fieldset > div [class^="tooltip-"],
            .fieldset > div [class*=" tooltip-"] {
                text-align: center;
                width: 30px;
            }
```

**How can I stop the icon width from changing according to the `<p>` above it?** which is not even contained within the same Div.

Comment: Can't you give a fixed width to `.fieldset > div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this.  Your mark-up is good, no changes required.

First, I would apply `display: table` to the child `div` and let the `p` element be a regular block or inline-block (depends on your design).

You can now set the width of the first table-cell element (`span`) to 1% and get the shrink-to-fit width that you need.

In your original CSS, the `p` element was being wrapped by anonymous table-cell and table-row elements. The net result was that the width of the first table-cell column was being determined by the width of the `p` text, not the width of the icon.

```css
/*Fieldsets*/

.fieldset {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.fieldset:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*Fieldsets > Labels*/

.fieldset > p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
/*Fieldsets > Input Container*/

.fieldset > div {
  display: table;
}
.fieldset > div > * {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
/*Fieldsets > Input + Icon*/

.fieldset > div > span {
  border: 1px solid #B0C2CE;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 1%;
}
/*Fieldsets > Input + Icon Senarios*/

.fieldset > div > span:first-of-type {
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.fieldset > div > span + input {
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: auto;
}
.fieldset > div > input + span {
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
.fieldset > div > span + input,
.fieldset > div > span + textarea,
.fieldset > div > span + select,
.fieldset > div > span + .select-dropdown-single .select-dropdown-input,
.fieldset > div > span + .select-dropdown-multi .select-input {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
/*Fieldsets > Input + Help ToolTip Icon*/

.fieldset > div [class^="tooltip-"],
.fieldset > div [class*=" tooltip-"] {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldset">
  <p>Normal Input</p>
  <div>
    <span><i class="icon-cart">Icon</i></span>
    <input name="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, the only reason I did not try this is becouse I thought you need to have the structure set-up as table the row then cell and not table then cell. Would it be fine to keep it as it is ? table then cell? without a row?

Comment: You only need to define a table-row element if you need to make sure that elements keep within rows.  If you define table then table-cell, an anonymous table-row element is generated internally by the CSS layout engine.

Comment: So it is safe to use yes?

Comment: Indeed it is, the CSS specification actually mentions that the CSS engine will create as many anonymous elements as needed to have a valid table.  In fact, you can have a single element designated as table-cell and the internal layout will generate an anonymous table-row and table as needed, pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*Fieldsets > Input + Icon*/
.fieldset > div > span {
    border: 1px solid #B0C2CE;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 10px; // This will set the width
    display:inline-block; // Add this and width will work.
}
```

Comment: It will work but not as I want it be, the height of the span will no more adapt to match the height of the cell next to it.

Comment: Then put a height on the input to match the height of the span?

Comment: I need it so it adapts automatically - that is the whole point of having it inside a table. Please is there another way of achieving the save results?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to place your *p* tag outside *.fieldset*. So it will not be in block with *display: table*. I think it makes sense to not put block element at table root level like

```
<table>
  <p></p>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By moving *p* outside you will remove the impact that *p* cause on your element with *display: table-cell*

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mandarin6b0/84dLk9gj/)

Or change your css, so the *display: block* element will not be within *display: table* element